# Saving YouTube video with VLC fails - only creates 1kb file with header

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am using VLC 3.0.18, and trying to save a YouTube video.

I *can* watch the video, using VLC., but when I try to convert or stream, regardless of which check-boxes I pick, the created file (eg "JunkVLC.MP4") has no content other than a header.  Using Notepad++, the [short] output file looks like this (with bunches of NULs stuck here/there): `moov lmvhd àÏåÃàÏåÃ _ @ ,udta $©enc vlc 3.0.18 stream output`

Nothing is dumped in to the output file, beyond this header.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong with the capture.

To my surprise, some settings for check boxes that I would expect to not display the video as the conversion occurs, does so anyway. If I attempt to do only the first 5 seconds, that request does nothing different -- the video displays to the full length.

If I merely "play", VLC works, but will ignore "stop at 5 seconds". The code it auto-generates is: :network-caching=1000 :stop-time=5.000

The media and codec info looks normal -- it is playing after all.

I am perplexed, as it is behaving as if ... well ... as if the more complex utility of VLC will not behave -- :( .

I've tried permutations of settings in VLC (it has, after all, worked to convert/stream in the the past).  I've uninstalled and cleared the remnants of VLC and re-installed the 3.0.18 64-bit version on to my windows 11 nifty box.

Because I can't get past this whole problem, I won't even begin to think of how to get the YouTube video in lower density (by adding some variant of .../?=720p or whatever is currently looked on kindly by the YouTube servers)

Guidance appreciate in advance ...

Comment: JDownloader2 is the best option in my experience for downloading YouTube videos. It's free and is able to detect all the MP4 files embedded in all quality streams. It also has FFMPEG conversion built-in for downloading as 360p, 480p, 720p or 1080p. Also allows you to download audio only.

Comment: @Mastaxx - yup. I was avoiding mentioning it until now, in case someone can answer this as asked. idk whether YT is just blocking this with some DRM-type protection, but JDownloader will do it.

Comment: Thank you both.   I am trying to minimize 3d party software counts, for various reasons.   The curious part , Mastaxx, is that I .can. view the files.   Given I can view, and all the quirks of usage I reported, I sense something is going on broader than, and other than, a YT block.  I am mis-using the program?  There's a setting I missed?  3.0.18 has better and more glorious bugs......?